# Type is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.6.1, nswag

I am using this command postbuild in .net 4.6.1 web api project.

> $(NSwagExe) aspnetcore2swagger "/assembly:$(TargetPath)"
>   "/output:$(OutputPath)swagger.json"

However it's failing on 2 places, first one is,

> 1>System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file
>   'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical
>   path is 'C:\Users\XXXX\source\Workspaces\Information
>   Systems\SOLUTION\SOLUTION.Api\bin\x64\Debug\

appsettings.json file is in same directory as Startup.cs. And this is how I am getting it

```
  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
```

Now to move forward, just to make it work, if I hard code path it works but I get this error then,

> 5>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type
>   'StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException' in Assembly
>   'StructureMap, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   is not marked as serializable.

Here is one of places in startup where I am using this structuremap,

```
   Start.LogicContainer.Configure(x => x.For<DBContext>().Use<DBContext>()
                .Ctor<string>("nameOrConnectionString").Is(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

All I want is to generate swagger.json file on each build.